# why curl options cors not resolve host and enable cors for all

Tags: javascript, php

some people get cors problem at their website because its blocked.

in PHP I have this header:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, 
    Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers, Authorization");
```

in .htaccess server file I have this:

```
# Enable cross domain access control
SetEnvIf Origin "^http(s)?://(.+\.)?(mietkauf-pkw\.de)$" REQUEST_ORIGIN=$0
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{REQUEST_ORIGIN}e env=REQUEST_ORIGIN
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-test-header, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true

# Force to request 200 for options
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule .* / [R=200,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mietkauf-pkw.de/$1 [R=301,L]
```

So I test a curl with options:

```
curl -H "Origin: https://mietkauf-pkw.de" \ -H 'Access-Control-Request-Method: POST' \ -H "Access-Control-Request-Headers: X-Requested-With" \ -X OPTIONS --verbose \ "https://mietkauf-pkw.de/pages/login.php"
```

And get this error:

```
* Could not resolve host: \
* Closing connection 0
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: \
* Could not resolve host: POST'
* Closing connection 1
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: POST'
* Could not resolve host: \
* Closing connection 2
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: \
* Could not resolve host: \
* Closing connection 3
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: \
* Could not resolve host: \
* Closing connection 4

*   Trying 2001:8d8:100f:f000::200:443...
* Connected to mietkauf-pkw.de (2001:8d8:100f:f000::200) port 443 (#5)
* schannel: disabled automatic use of client certificate
* ALPN: offers http/1.1
* ALPN: server accepted http/1.1
> OPTIONS /pages/login.php HTTP/1.1
> Host: mietkauf-pkw.de
> User-Agent: curl/7.83.1
> Accept: */*
> Origin: https://mietkauf-pkw.de
> Access-Control-Request-Headers: X-Requested-With
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
< Content-Length: 476
< Connection: keep-alive
< Keep-Alive: timeout=15
< Date: Sun, 19 Mar 2023 17:36:35 GMT
< Server: Apache
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://mietkauf-pkw.de
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-test-header, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
<
```

So what I am doing wrong and how can I enable cors for all ?

I allowed all cors with * and I created a htacess file where I allowed but some people can not see the content because fetch not works sometimes because its blocked. can anyone help me please

Comment: Start by getting the actual verbatim error message the browser console shows in those cases. It is pretty pointless to take a stab in the dark with little more information than _"some people can not see the content because fetch not works sometimes because its blocked"_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `curl` call is on one line, but it uses backslashes as though it had been meant to be spread across multiple lines. The backslashes escape the space after them, which means it gets fed into `curl`, which can't resolve a host with the name   (space).

Either remove the backslashes:

```bash
curl -H "Origin: https://mietkauf-pkw.de" -H 'Access-Control-Request-Method: POST' -H "Access-Control-Request-Headers: X-Requested-With" -X OPTIONS --verbose "https://mietkauf-pkw.de/pages/login.php"
```

or follow the backslashes with newlines:

```
curl -H "Origin: https://mietkauf-pkw.de" \
-H 'Access-Control-Request-Method: POST' \
-H "Access-Control-Request-Headers: X-Requested-With" \
-X OPTIONS --verbose \
"https://mietkauf-pkw.de/pages/login.php"
```

---

I think your question is just about the `curl` call, but just in case it's (also) about CORS headers:

If you want **any** origin to be able to do **anything at all**, you can use wildcards for all three main CORS headers, and possibly allow auth as well:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
```

Needless to say, it's **really, really important that you don't store any client-confidential information**, since this bypasses the [Same Origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy), which is there to protect user information.

Comment: hey thanks, but why I get connect resvoled host when using the curl options request

Comment: @newexe91 - I don't know what you mean by that.

Comment: if I make a request with CURL with OPTIONS then I get  Could not resolve host: \
* Closing connection 0

Comment: @newexe91 - It's just a mistake on the `curl` command line, I've updated the answer. Sorry I didn't fully get the question at first.

Comment: Thanks for updating at the last command I get 6x could not resolved host, now one times * Could not resolve host: POST'
* Closing connection 0, I check it with test cors online site with options and they said it works perfect https://cors-test.codehappy.dev/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fmietkauf-pkw.de%2Fpages%2Flogin.php&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fmietkauf-pkw.de&method=options

Comment: @newexe91 - Don't know what to tell you, when I do the call with either of my two examples above, it works: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3Xia.png, https://i.stack.imgur.com/puTut.png (That is: the `curl` call works. The server runs into a problem, but the `curl` call works.)

Comment: thanks! How can I solve this when the server runs into the problem with options ?

Comment: @newexe91 - You'll have to debug it. I don't think we can help you do that with the information that's in the question.